Fishbone rigging questions

I modeled the fish and am going to rig it.
But I'm stuck, so I'm asking.
The rakes on the back of the fish have a lot of bones because they need to be able to wave.
However, the parts that move the entire fish have fewer bones compared to that. How should I rig it in this case?
The method I thought of was to 'pin' the rakes' bones to the vertices on the back of the fish, but I don't know how to do this either.
*The rakes on the back of the fish and the fish are not one model.
The movement I want to create>>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vSTFMXjrrpI

Hi, I think it would be beneficial if you could upload screenshots of the entire skeleton and the mesh of the fish.
